# Shall we edit the Help Centre page on generative A.I.?

Tags: discussion, policy, help-center

S.E. have added a new help page on the use of generative A.I. to write answers:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy

I think what's lacking is any reminder that whoever posts an answer is responsible for its being correct & relevant; merely acknowledging generative A.I. use doesn't legitimate recklessly posting potential nonsense. We've discussed this in a couple of Meta posts:

[What's the policy on Human/AI collaboration for answering questions?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6445/17230)

[What to do about answers written by ChatGPT](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6422/17230)

We can edit the help page: I propose we do that after consideration of proposed changes here.

Comment: For once, my upvote means "Good idea" not "Good question".

Comment: The above should be interpreted this way: On Meta, upvoting a question is generally to be interpreted as "This is a good question to ask" and not necessarily as agreeing with any proposal or viewpoint contained therein.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [Scortchi - Reinstate Monica](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6646/362671)'s assessment that merely acknowledging the usage of generative AI in one's post doesn't give them the right to open the floodgates of blindly dumping the content, irrespective of gauging the veracity and soundness of the same.

Thus, it should be explicitly stated as mentioned in the question.

(I suppose one might upvote this post to show agreement; but again this can be done by directly upvoting the, in words of Nick Cox, "Good idea".)

Comment: I upvoted this too.

Comment: +1. Perhaps we want to include links to the relevant Meta threads on the Help Center page. I personally would advocate including a *very* conspicuous notification along the lines of **"If you post GenAI-generated crap, it WILL be downvoted and deleted, and you WILL be banned."**

Comment: Sure @StephanKolassa. I might be bit of pessimistic when I say I can't find any potential answer to be useful where someone used generative AI. Once we have a collective consent on the proposal, we can come to agreement the final statement (I second yours) that would appear in the page.

Comment: I think or rather hope that @StephanKolassa is joking a little. We shouldn't need or seek new criteria for downvoting, deleting or banning.  Trouble is that none of us would recognise a really good AI-produced answer as it would be indistinguishable from any other kind. But garbage is always garbage, whether generated by the utterly clueless, the  utterly confused, or some unutterable code.

Comment: Perhaps we could tone down the insolent style of the statement Stephan has stated without disagreeing with the implicit sentiment. Sure, it would be too much to warrant a straight banning, but certainly the statement could indicate _resorting to the practice of adopting generative AI content without proper vetting is discouraged and continued usage of such might lead to ----_ @NickCox.

Comment: @User1865345 Inam not sure you find it a useful answer but in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/638721/164061) I used the help of AI to generate the image. I am not such a code monkey that I know the ins and outs of igraph so I asked the computer to make an initial sketch of the graph and it also helped me answering questions about how to modify colours text locations etc.

Comment: @User1865345: I took the liberty of submitting both "f you post GenAI-generated crap, it WILL be downvoted and deleted, and you WILL be banned" and "resorting to the practice of adopting generative AI content without proper vetting is discouraged and continued usage of such might lead to" to https://textinspector.com. The first statement got a Flesch-Kincaide Grade of 8.39, the second 13.91. I personally would rather err on the side of understandability. Of course, we can tune it down. Also, please note that I do not advocate banning for GenAI content, but for GenAI-generated *crap*.

Comment: Sure @StephanKolassa, I am all in what you stated and agree with that we are not against the whole exclusion of GenAI content but rather the practice of dumping anything based on those without proper checking.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, that's actually an interesting use and the output of the Markov chain turned out nice indeed.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: [your comment](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6646/shall-we-edit-the-help-centre-page-on-generative-a-i/6647?noredirect=1#comment22765_6647) sounds like "any content crafted, in part or in whole, using a tool that writes a response automatically based on a prompt it is provided", so it looks like you should have credited AI?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I see now that my answer may not have been such a great example of the use of AI that is intended in this meta-question. Isn't crediting only for creative original content? If I make a post with the help of spelling control and grammar improvements and I made calculations with the help of Wolfram alpha and I used Google to search for information, do I need to credit all three programs?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: that is an excellent question. For that specific question, I honestly don't think you need to credit anything, since your use of GenAI rather obviously did not go much beyond googling for an example of how to create this graphic. But by the text of our help page, you indeed seem to have to credit it ("crafted in part"). It's hard to find the golden mean here.